# Is there any default button for mapKit to allow user to change the orientation of the map from device heading to North up?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, mapkit

I am using mapKit and would like to have several buttons.

One is to change the orientation or the map from North Up to the device heading.  Another is to center on the user's location and finally to change between satellite and hybrid maps.

This is available on the maps app with the info and direction button and I have no problem to use my own custom implementation to achieve this.  But before doing so I was wondering if mapKit has this functionality already built in?

Is there any option to add the above mentioned functionality to a mapView without implementing the buttons and logic myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a button named `MKUserTrackingButton`. ([You can read more about it here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkusertrackingbutton))

To implement it, you should set `userTrackingMode` property. ([See more](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1616208-usertrackingmode))

It is available on iOS11.0+, so it should do the job.